# Remove an element from array of structs with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have to implement the `appointmentData_remove` function which removes an element of type `tAppointment` from the `tAppointmentData` array.

Data types are defined like this:

```
// Type that stores a vaccination appointment data
typedef struct _tAppointment {    
    tDateTime timestamp;
    tPerson* person;
    tVaccine* vaccine;
} tAppointment;

// Type that stores a list of vaccination appointments
typedef struct _tAppointmentData {    
    tAppointment* elems;
    // Number of elements
    int count;    
} tAppointmentData;

typedef struct _tPerson {
    char* document;
    char* name;
    char* surname;
    char* cp;
    char* email;
    char* address;
    tDate birthday;
} tPerson;

typedef struct _tVaccine {
    char *name;
    int required;
    int days;
} tVaccine;

typedef struct _tDate {    
    int day; 
    int month;
    int year;
} tDate;

typedef struct _tTime {
    int hour; 
    int minutes;
} tTime;

typedef struct _tDateTime {
    tDate date;
    tTime time;    
} tDateTime;
```

The function should check if a certain condition meets in order to find the index of the element to remove.
So far I have developed the following but the only result i get is a decrement on `count` but I can't get the elements to shift to the right position.

```
void appointmentData_remove(tAppointmentData* list, tDateTime timestamp, tPerson* person) {

int i, j;
    
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    for (i=0;i<list->count;i++) {
        if (condition) {
            j = i;
            for (i=j;i<list->count;i++) {
                list->elems[i].person = list->elems[i+1].person;
                list->elems[i].vaccine = list->elems[i+1].vaccine;
                list->elems[i].timestamp = list->elems[i+1].timestamp;
                }
        list->count --;
        }
    }
}
```

For example if the element to delete is at index `0`  I understand that it should be replaced with the element `1`, and index `1`with index `2`, etc.. but for some reason the loop isn't working. Any thoughts?? Thank you.

Comment: And this reason is? What is your efforts to track down an error?

Comment: I think you invert i and j on the second `for` loop

Comment: Your *move the remaining elements forward* in the list should be `list->elems[i].person = list->elems[i+1+j].person;` with `j` starting at `0` and getting incremented by `1` at each found occurrence.